# How to dynamically do Vuex hot reloading for modules?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuex, vuex-modules

I use the following code which simply gets all modules to apply Vuex hot reloading. However, the following code doesn't work at all.

```
if (module.hot) {
    const modules = Object.keys(store._modules.root._children)
    module.hot.accept([...modules.map(x => "./modules/" + x)], () => {
        const items = {}

        modules.map(mod => {
            items[mod] = require("./modules/" + mod).default
        })
        store.hotUpdate({
            modules: items
        })
    })
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: the documentation shows key pair value on  `modules: {  a: newModuleA }` I'm not saying this is the problem but let's try removing concerns one by one. Also your items is a const. Change it to a let.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry for late reply but it didn't work after changing const to let. But const and let shouldn't matter unless I change the variable directly to something else. I think it's okay to do `modules.a = 'b'` in a const object.

Comment: What about the key pair values from the things that come from the store?

Comment: Altogether, `Object.keys` return the module names like `["auth", "pages"]`